# Unique ID based on a group and a column condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create trip number for a data. The data contains the vehicle ID and time stamp. All timestamps which are close to each other for same ID are considered to be part of a single trip. If the time diff between consecutive ID is greater than 1 hr, I want it to be considered as a new trip.

Sample Data:

```
data<-data.frame(ID = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'), date = c('2018-13-3 09:20:25','2018-13-3 09:23:42','2018-13-3 09:34:08','2018-13-3 11:25:25','2018-13-3 11:32:25','2018-13-3 11:33:42','2018-13-3 11:34:08','2018-13-3 11:36:25','2018-13-3 11:40:25','2018-13-3 11:23:42','2018-13-3 11:24:08','2018-13-3 11:25:25','2018-13-3 12:32:25','2018-13-3 12:33:42','2018-13-3 15:34:08','2018-13-3 15:36:25','2018-13-3 15:37:25','2018-13-3 15:38:25'))
```

Expected Output:

```
ID         date         Trip  
A   2018-13-3 09:20:25   1  
A   2018-13-3 09:23:42   1  
A   2018-13-3 09:34:08   1  
A   2018-13-3 11:25:25   2  
A   2018-13-3 11:32:25   2  
A   2018-13-3 11:33:42   2  
A   2018-13-3 11:34:08   2  
A   2018-13-3 11:36:25   2  
A   2018-13-3 11:40:25   2  
B   2018-13-3 11:23:42   1  
B   2018-13-3 11:24:08   1  
B   2018-13-3 11:25:25   1  
B   2018-13-3 12:32:25   2  
B   2018-13-3 12:33:42   2  
B   2018-13-3 15:34:08   3  
B   2018-13-3 15:36:25   3  
B   2018-13-3 15:36:25   3  
B   2018-13-3 15:36:25   3
```

I am currently trying to do it with a for loop which is not optimized in R. Can anyone help me with a more effective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'date' to Datetime class, grouped by 'ID', check if the difference between the adjacent elements of 'date' is greater than 1, get the cumulative sum of the logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
     mutate(date = ydm_hms(date)) %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(Trip = cumsum(difftime(date, lag(date,default = date[1]), unit = 'hour')> 1) + 1)

# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups: ID [2]
#   ID     date                 Trip
#  <fctr> <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 A      2018-03-13 09:20:25  1.00
# 2 A      2018-03-13 09:23:42  1.00
# 3 A      2018-03-13 09:34:08  1.00
# 4 A      2018-03-13 11:25:25  2.00
# 5 A      2018-03-13 11:32:25  2.00
# 6 A      2018-03-13 11:33:42  2.00
# 7 A      2018-03-13 11:34:08  2.00
# 8 A      2018-03-13 11:36:25  2.00
# 9 A      2018-03-13 11:40:25  2.00
#10 B      2018-03-13 11:23:42  1.00
#11 B      2018-03-13 11:24:08  1.00
#12 B      2018-03-13 11:25:25  1.00
#13 B      2018-03-13 12:32:25  2.00
#14 B      2018-03-13 12:33:42  2.00
#15 B      2018-03-13 15:34:08  3.00
#16 B      2018-03-13 15:36:25  3.00
#17 B      2018-03-13 15:37:25  3.00
#18 B      2018-03-13 15:38:25  3.00
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)